# What is "IDL-exposed autofill value" in HTML Autocomplete context?

Tags: html

Can somebody make me understand this term, What is "IDL-exposed autofill value".

Here's the link it is being used - https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#autofill-processing-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the value that is returned in JavaScript when you get `input.autocomplete`.

In the algorithm that follows that the text that you link to, it describes how this value is computed from the content attribute `<input autocomplete="..." >`